# How to repeat the indices of a vector based on the values of that same vector?

Tags: r, vector, indices

Given a random integer vector below:

```
z <- c(3, 2, 4, 2, 1)
```

I'd like to create a new vector that contains all z's indices a number of times specified by the value corresponding to that element of z. To illustrate this. The desired result in this case should be:

```
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5
```

There must be a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rep` and `seq` *to repeat the indices of a vector based on the values of that same vector*. `seq` to get the *indices* and `rep` to *repeat* them.

```
rep(seq(z), z)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5
```

Comment: That's a lightning fast answer and a way shorter and elegant solution. Thanks GKi!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with all the indices of the vector z. These are given by:

```
1:length(z)
```

Then these elements should be repeated. The number of times these numbers should be repeated is specified by the values of z. This can be done using a combination of the `lapply` or `sapply` function and the `rep` function:

```
unlist(lapply(X = 1:length(z), FUN = function(x) rep(x = x, times = z[x])))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5

unlist(sapply(X = 1:length(z), FUN = function(x) rep(x = x, times = z[x])))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5
```

Both alternatives give the same result.